# repeat the command where condition is true within while loop using scanner

Tags: java

How do I get the code below to repeat the command, where the players name already exists in the key set?

```
public static Map<String, Player> players = new TreeMap<>();

 for (int loop = 1; loop <= 4; loop++) {
        
        System.out.println("enter player"+loop+"s name");
        name = scanner.next();
        if(players.keySet().contains(name)) {
            System.out.println("name in use - enter new name");
        }else {
            players.put(name, new Player());
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable (e.g. `boolean alreadyExists` as shown in the code below) to track a valid input and loop back in case of invlid input.

```
boolean alreadyExists;

for (int loop = 1; loop <= 4; loop++) {
    do {
        alreadyExists = false;
        System.out.println("enter player" + loop + "s name");
        name = scanner.next();
        if (players.keySet().contains(name)) {
            System.out.println("name in use - enter new name");
            alreadyExists = true;
        } else {
            players.put(name, new Player());
        }
    } while (alreadyExists);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need a limited number of valid players.

```
while (players.size() < 4) {
        name = scanner.next();
        if(players.keySet().contains(name)) {
            System.out.println("name in use - enter new name");
        } else {
            players.put(name, new Player());
        }
}
```